# What kind of hot water system is this?

Tags: plumbing, hot-water

I have a basic question that will surely be very easy for anybody less awful at this kind of thing than me: this is an electric hot water system, right? What are the various inlets/outlets/valves?

(If it's relevant, this is in Sydney, Australia.)

[image: Hot water system]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what I see, the green pipe is the hot out supply to the house as that is on the output of the temperature mitigating valve. The green cap can usually be adjusted - some need pulling out to allow movement (a safety feature to prevent accidental changes), take care if you want to change the temperature though, a usual maximum is 46 deg C but often they are set lower like 42 deg C.

The pipe coming to that mitigating valve is the cold supply which also is connected to the bottom of the tank ie the supply point.

The pipe further back to the right is from the pressure & temperature relief valve so that the tank is not damaged due to an excess of pressure or temperature.

Comment: Ah thanks, the mitigating valve is the part that confused me; haven’t seen that before. So to be clear this is for sure electric and not gas, right?

Comment: I don't see a gas flue and the black cable at the back left looks like the electric supply.

Comment: Are those mitigating valves common on all heaters now? +

Comment: @JACK I know for sure they are a legal requirement on solar systems (in two countries I am aware of the regulastions) as they can often exceed 90 deg C, and I am not sure if they are a legal requirement on gas or electric systems but as systems can fail in heating mode then they would be a commonsense addition.